# Undeclared prefix while setting InnerXml

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I want to write out a XML-File but during build up the XMLDocument by setting InnerXml I get the following error:

> 'gml' is an undeclared prefix

```
XmlDocument docXML = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode myRoot = docXML.CreateElement("xplan:XPlanAuszug");
string gmlNS = @"http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2";
myRoot.Attributes.Append(docXML.CreateAttribute("xmlns:gml")).InnerText = gmlNS;
docXML.AppendChild(myRoot);
..    
XmlNode boundedBy = docXML.CreateElement("gml:boundedBy", gmlNS);
boundedBy.InnerXml = dr["bbox"].ToString();
myRoot.AppendChild(boundedBy);
```

In dr["bbox"] is something like this:

```
<gml:Envelope srsName="EPSG:25832"><gml:lowerCorner>32622352 5744796</gml:lowerCorner><gml:upperCorner>32622430 5744910</gml:upperCorner></gml:Envelope>
```

Seems the error occurs when parsing xml from database and put it into inner xml. How can the undeclared namespace being ignored?

Comment: @Charlieface I get a compiling error "XmlNode" enthält keine Definition für "SetAttribute", und es wurde keine verfügbare SetAttribute-Erweiterungsmethode gefunden...

Comment: @Charlieface var works, but I get the same error 'gml' is an undeclared prefix

Comment: The attribute is created on the `<xplan:XPlanAuszug>` node, but `<gml:boundedBy>` is being created on the base document node. Perhaps you need to create the attribute on `docXML` alternatively create `<gml:boundedBy>` in `<xplan:XPlanAuszug>`

Comment: @Charlieface Solution is first to AppendChild and then set InnerXml :) Thx!!!! I only have to turn the last 2 rows

Comment: It is better to use LINQ to XML API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.